# MS SQL Server 2012 Express edition does not use Visual Studio 2012 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I installed VS 2012 Express and then later installed MS SQL Server 2012 Express with Tools.

Oddly, I now have two Visual Studio IDE's: the 2010 version that works with MS SQL Server 2012 projects and the 2012 Version that works with c#, vb, C++ projects...

How can I get the MS SQL Server projects to show in VS 2012 alongside c#, vb and C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Wait until 2013 comes out? They're behind on SQL Server Management Studio and VS, kind of how Visio was behind when the Office Ribbon came out and how Office was behind when Windows 8 came out.